# Hamiltonian for a particle with central force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism

I am asked to write a detailed Hamiltonian function for a particle moving in a central potential using spherical coordinates. It feels like i got it right, but I'm not sure if it's "detailed" enough. Can someone please check it?
My progress:

Lagrangian:
$$L = T - V = \frac m {2}(\dot{r^2} + r^2  \dot{\theta^2} + r  sin^2(\theta)  \dot\phi^2) - V(r)$$
Generalised impulses:
$$p_r = m  \dot{r}$$
$$p_\theta = m  r^2  \dot{\theta}$$
$$p_\phi = m  r^2  sin^2(\theta)  \dot{\phi}$$
And the Hamiltonian is:
$$H =  \frac 1 {2m}(p_r^2 + \frac {p_\theta^2} {r^2}+ \frac {p_\phi^2} {sin^2(\theta) r^2})+V(r)$$

The main concern is the potential, since it's central it only depends on r and since it's not given, I assume it's just V(r), is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, it's correct absolutely as there is no specifically force mentioned here, you can take $V(r)$ in general..

In fact you can write $V(r)=V_{\text{effective}} + J^2/(2×m×r^2)$.